# Stata - r-class command - Guidance

Tags: stata

Is there anybody who could give me a first hint on how to program an r-class command in Stata? Also a helpful link containing instructions or guidance would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The original and in many ways best introduction is in the later chapters of the User's Guide. That's bundled with Stata as a .pdf. See also Kit Baum's text http://www.stata.com/bookstore/stata-programming-introduction/

Comment: `help program` in Stata will list the resources included with Stata, which--while not free--do not require purchase of a book. The book is a good one though.